# Setting default keyboard layout in Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-8, windows-server-2012

When there are multiple input methods (keyboard layouts) installed, the first one in the list is supposed to be the default. In my case I have two custom keyboard layouts:

- US (Customized)
- Czech (Customized)

[image: My currently installed keyboard layouts (input methods)]

So the first option—*US (Customized)*—should be the default option. The advanced settings dialog confirms this as well as shows the layouts in the same order:

[image: Keyboard Advanced settings in Windows Server 2012]

Also, the keyboard layout switching pop-up shows *US (Customized)* at the top and *Czech (Customized)* below.

However, when login into the system, the *second*, or maybe *last one*, is selected by default, i.e. the *Czech (Customized)* option. Is this a bug in the OS or am I missing something? Note that I experience the same behavior when I copy the input methods to the login screen settings—when logging-in, the default isn't the first on the list.

So how does the auto-selection of the default keyboard layout really work in Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012, when there's no override in place in the advanced settings?

Comment: I have the same problem and I almost never login myself on the first try. There should be some option for the login screen to always use the default language.

Comment: I think it's a bug. I have exactly the same problem, only worse. I have an input method of UK English with US-DVORAK keyboard, and Spanish with a Spanish keyboard. On top of sometimes defaulting to Spanish (my secondary input language), it also sometimes gives me UK English with a UK keyboard, which is not even configured at all in the input settings!

Comment: @OliverSalzburg What's the reason for removing the `keyboard-layout` tag?

Comment: @OndrejTucny: It's not a useful tag. Tags should optimally be an area of expertise and/or interest. Categorizing a question with a tag for an operating system is obviously helpful, because people might be knowledgeable about that system (or not interested at all in it). Keyboard layouts aren't really a helpful categorization if you imagine all the different types of questions that fit into it.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I believe a `windows-8` *and* `keyboard-layout` tags applied together do make for the necessary distinction. At least we use tags this way on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @OndrejTucny: We generally don't like tags that only work in combination with other tags.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg That just doesn't make sense. `windows-8` *alone* **does not** make sense because it can easily account for 10 % of SuperUser's content. Will ask about it on Meta.

Comment: @OndrejTucny You are 100% right and the guy who removed the tag is 100% wrong. "We generally don't like tags that …" - wtf? StackOverflow and SuperUser really aren't on the same level. While the former is a great site, SU abounds with patronizing, arrogant admins à la Wikipedia who make high-handed edits to posts, delete comments, and even entire questions should the discussion in the comments threaten to expose the ignorance that underpins their purported superuser/superadmin status. Well, the name of the site is »superuser«, nomen est omen.

Answer (score 8):

It's not a bug, it's a feature! To set input language of the login screen open the control panel "Control Panel > Clock, Language, and Region > Language". Click at the link Advanced settings. Set the Windows display language and input method as you want it. Then click at the link Apply language settings to the welcome screen etc. Click at the button Copy settings. Click at the checkbox Copy settings to Welcome screen and system accounts. Click OK. Close all windows. Log out.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem of a VNC service using the wrong keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1):

In *Advanced settings*

1. Change *Override default input language* to *English*
2. Choose *Let me set a different input method for each app window*
3. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly related to your question, as you specifically mention that your problem occurs on the login screen, but many others have encountered a bug in Windows 8 where the keyboard language switched at random.

Having followed [the brief discussion on this forum post](http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=61899), it appears that if you specify the keyboard languages under separate languages, the keyboard language no longer randomly switches.

Specifically, in my scenario, I had English (United States) with a US keyboard and United States-International keyboard. I resolved my problem by removing the US International keyboard and adding Dutch as a new language with that keyboard. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> still works as previously.